# how to return value in PHPrecursive function

Tags: php, recursion

i am trying to build a recursive tree but child function is not returning any value. i don't know how to return value in PHP code. is there i am doing any mistake. please help

```
 $sql="select * from MenuMaster order by MenuId";
        $result= ExecuteQuery($sql);
    function BuildMenu($result){
        $output ='';
        $output .= '<Ul>';

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result)){
            if($row['ParentId']== null || $row['ParentId'] ==0){
                $output .= '<li>'.$row['MenuText'].'</li>';
            }
             $output .= FindChild($output , $row['MenuId']);
        }

        $output.= '</Ul>';
        return $output;
    }
    $finaloutput.= BuildMenu($result);
    echo $finaloutput;




function FindChild($childOutput, $Menuid){

    $sqlChild="select * from MenuMaster where ParentId = $Menuid ";
    $resultChild= ExecuteQuery($sqlChild);
    $Rowcont =mysqli_num_rows($resultChild);


    if($Rowcont > 0){
      $childOutput.='<Ul>';

        while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array ($resultChild)){
            $childOutput.= '<li>'.$row1['MenuText'].'</li>';
            FindChild($childOutput,$row1['MenuId']);
        }
        $childOutput.='</Ul>';
    }
        return  $childOutput;
      }
```

Comment: Please, post the code not pictures.

Comment: i am sorry for this. i am new over this forum and facing problem while copy paste code here

Comment: How to use the editor is described. Here you just paste your code and take care to format it using the "Code" button at the top of the entry field.

Comment: If the function `FindChild()` does not return anything then the SQL statement does not return any rows.

Comment: i have formatted now my code please help. @mega6382

Comment: inside FindChild you don't do anything with the return of FindChild. You'd need to add that return to `$childoutput`: `$childOutput.=FindChild($childOutput,$row1['MenuId']);`

Comment: please explain in detail or edit my code thanks @Jeff

Comment: I've edited my comment and pasted the corrected line there.

Comment: couldn't understand @Jeff

Comment: The nested calls to `FindChild()` won't influence the result, since whatever modifications you do is lost. You hand over the result so far as a runtime argument (not as a reference!). Then, in the inner run you manipulate it. Note that the variable `$childOutput` in the inner run has _nothing_ to do with the variable of the same name in the outer run. Ok, you `return` that value, but you ignore the return value in the 6th last line of your code. Just as @NeerajSinghChouhan pointed out.